# Count number of ones in first two columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rowsum

Say, I have a data frame as below, having three columns. I would like to create a fourth column whose value is the sum of the number of ones in the first two columns put together

An iterative version

```
col1 = c(1,1,1,0,0)
col2 = c(1,0,0,0,1)
col3 = c(0,1,1,1,0)

df = data.frame(col1,col2,col3)
df$col4 = 0;

for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
    print(i)
    countone = 0
    for(j in 1:2)
    {
        if(df[i,j] == 1)
        {
            countone = countone + 1;
        }
    }   

    df[i,4] = countone
}
```

Input

```
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    1    0
2    1    0    1
3    1    0    1
4    0    0    1
5    0    1    0
```

Expected Output

```
> df
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1    1    0    2
2    1    0    1    1
3    1    0    1    1
4    0    0    1    0
5    0    1    0    1
```

Comment: Probably a bit more efficient version would be ````Reduce(`+`, df[, 1:2])````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$col4 <- rowSums(df[,1:2])
```

That's called a row-sum.
And there is no need for the initialization line: `df$col4 = 0`.

( This code works because we are given those entries can only be 0 or 1. Something that works on more general code would be `rowSums(df[,1:2]==1)`, with `... na.rm = T` if needed. )